# How to list out product details from click bank API and XML?

Tags: php, xml, api, xmlhttprequest, clickbank

This is my sample code for click bank API unfortunately this script do not work

Here is the sample code:

```
 <?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/products/list");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/xml", "Authorization: DEV:CLERK"));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);
?>
```

If run this code following error has occur

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Date: Sat, 23 Feb 2013 05:24:10 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.23 (FreeBSD) mod_jk/1.2.37 mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8x Vary: Accept-Encoding Connection: close Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/plain The API call (/api/rest/1.3/products/list) requires parameters which are missing : [site]1

Comment: requires parameters which are missing : [site]1 - you're missing a parameter to the call, looks like it should be named 'site'

Comment: Hi @  Nicholas Pickering  where we can pass a parameter 'site' and please give me a sample code for this?

Comment: Hi @ Nicholas Pickering what is a  [site]1 parameter how can i get it Please Explain

Comment: I've written an answer for you - with a link to the API you are working with

Answer (score 1):

https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/products

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.2/debug");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/xml", "Authorization: DEV:CLERK"));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: Hi@ Nicholas Pickering replace this code follwing error has occur HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden Date: Sat, 23 Feb 2013 06:34:17 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.23 (FreeBSD) mod_jk/1.2.37 mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8x Vary: Accept-Encoding Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/plain Access to account denied1 please help me

Comment: Did you replace www.domain.com with your website's URL?

Comment: @krishna let me know if it didn't.

Comment: Hi @ Nicholas Pickering i am using my domain name, but show the   follwing error has occur HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden Date: Sat, 23 Feb 2013 06:34:17 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.23 (FreeBSD) mod_jk/1.2.37 mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8x Vary: Accept-Encoding Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/plain Access to account denied1 please help me

Comment: @krishna run the code in my edited answer now instead of your code, and let me know what you get.

Comment: @krishna what is your website URL?

Comment: Hi @Nicholas Pickering  www.osiztechnologies.com this is my websiteurl

Comment: Hi  @Nicholas Pickering replace this script following information has displayed Header Parameters:
 Param:host, value :api.clickbank.com
 Param:accept, value :application/xml
 Param:authorization, value :DEV-0AA0863B00D0C8E3E4AAE3D39C59836B3333:API-189A6471A02308B646DFF780C015D2322FBB
 Param:content-length, value :0

Request Parameters: 1 please help me

Answer (score 0):

The required "site" parameter should be the Clickbank ID (also known as vendor).